# How can I static_assert the underlying element of a container?

Tags: c++

```
template <typename T>
MyFun(const T container)
{
    // I want to static_assert that all elements in T are equal to SomeType
}
```

How can I do this? I'm thinking something along the lines of `static_assert(std::is_same<T::type,SomeType>)` but that of course does not work...

Comment: How does it "not work"? What error do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use

```
 static_assert(std::is_same<typename T::value_type,SomeType>::value, "type in the container is different");
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is an standard container...

```
template <typename Container>
MyFun(const Constainer& container)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<typename Container::value_type, SomeType>::value)
    // I want to static_assert that all elements in Container are equal to SomeType
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need something like

```
static_assert(std::is_same<typename T::value_type, SomeType>::value, 
              "It does not work");
```

Assumng the container type defined `value_type` to be the type of the elements it holds (like standard library containers do).

See [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) and [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert).